# How to fix javascript can't run in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print something inside my html from a javascript. I don't know javascript much. I did this but it don't work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function title() {
var t = document.title;
document.write(t);
}
//]]>
</script>

<div>
      <span><script>title();</script></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you write the code yourself? Why do you use a CDATA block inside of your HTML-Code instead of writing the plain JavaScript function?

Comment: It doesn't look like a proper HTML. What do you expect to see after the JS function is executed? When do you want the JS function to be executed? Syntax errors as well.

Comment: It doesn't work because you have a syntax error; this `});` isn't necessary.

Comment: The code updated @SparkFountain

Comment: The code updated @Raptor

Comment: Sr @NikKyriakides I forgot to delete when I shortened the code

Comment: Better read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
let name = document.getElementById("name");

name.innerHTML = "hello world";
```

```html
<div itemprop='review' itemscope='' itemtype='https://schema.org/Review'>
  <div itemprop='itemReviewed' itemscope='' itemtype='https://schema.org/Product'>
    <span itemprop='name' id="name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fix your syntax error, and take away the CDATA you have a working bit of code. The reason why you *still* won't see any output is that, because you don't have a proper HTML document structure, there's no `title` to print...

Here's some updated code and an example of how to go about debugging using [console.log()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-console-log-with-examples/).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function title() {
        var t = document.title;
        // print the value of t to the console to test
        console.log( 'title is: ' + t );

        document.write(t);
    }
</script>

<div>
  <span>
      <script>title();</script>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an external JavaScript file and link it to your html page like this.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

and then define your function into app.js, like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.write("Hello, I'm here!");
}
```